# DocuSign eSignature for Salesforce Integration :Configuration of CRL parameter with optional Recipients

Tags: integration, docusign

I am using Docusign eSignature for Salesforce managed package for integration . Use case is to send Docusign envelope  using a screen flow, hence I'm using 'Send with Docusign' action provided by the package.  In my envelope configuration , I have 3 recipients (1 mandatory , 2 opitional) which are dynamically pulled from the source record. I configured advance parameter 'CRL' for this. This setup work fine as long all 3 recipients are available on the source record. If 1 or 2 recipient ( which are optional) are missing on the record the envelope creation errors out with
Error message : "Invalid envelope. Recipient must have an email address Recipient must have an email address" .

My configuration of CRL parameter is following, is there a way to make the Role~Joint Owner and  Role~Spouse as optional ?

Email~{!Withdrawal_Request__c.Owner_Email__c};Role~Owner;FirstName~{!Withdrawal_Request__c.FirstName__c};LastName~{!Withdrawal_Request__c.LastName__c}, Email~{!Withdrawal_Request__c.Joint_Owner_Email__c};Role~Joint Owner;FirstName~{!Withdrawal_Request__C.Joint_Owner_First_Name__c};LastName~{!Withdrawal_Request__C.Joint_Owner_Last_Name__c},Email~{!Withdrawal_Request__c.Owner_Spouse_Email__c};Role~Spouse;FirstName~{!Withdrawal_Request__C.Spouse_First_Name__c};LastName~{!Withdrawal_Request__C.Spouse_Last_Name__c};

Comment: You need to contact Docusign support.

Comment: @DavidCheng Thanks, contact them to confirm this functionality exist ? or to report this as an issue  ?